# Difficulty with Android library to keep as dependency

Tags: android

I have a few different apps and I want to create a module/library in Android Studio to re-use some activities, layouts and drawable in all of my apps, like an underlying framework.

I can only create a module within an app project, not as a separate project. I removed this folder from the app path to another folder outside this app (I want a separate Git repo for this). If I then import this module in my different app projects, it copies this module. So the changes I make in my current app project in the module, do not affect the module in my other app projects. I can't imagine I have to merge this manually every time. How to do, if not import? Further, if I open this module as a project with Android Studio, I can't build it because of  `apply plugin: com.android.library`.

I went through this page and some Google search, but I am still confused: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

- How is it possible to have a module or library which is re-usable (activities, layouts) in many apps and has its own repository?
- Is the only possibility to have the Android lib or module in one project and import in any other project as a .AAR ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From android studio project terminal add git sub-module

```
git submodule add https://XXX@bitbucket.org/YYY/ZZZ.git
```

make sure the sub module save location folder name is different than the original library project name, else you might get

- conflicts.
        select ‘Import Gradle Project’
        select the sub-module folder
        give the actual sub-module project name

Now you have an application project in git, which uses a library that is added to it as a submodule in git. Now you can develop on the application and on the library parallelly. It's better to keep a separate branch of the library for an application so as not to conflict with another application usage, and if the library code changes can be used in other projects also you can make a PR request to the main branch of the library.

for more references follow this link

https://medium.com/@deepakpk/how-to-add-a-git-android-library-project-as-a-sub-module-c713a653ab1f

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I am a bit struggling with this: `Prerequisite: an Android Library project under a repository`. I can't find a way to create an Android Lib without an app module.

Comment: Thanks! I finally managed to do what I wanted with the help of this description. What I have to add: the library can be committed without the entire "test project" and then it is easy to add again as a submodule in every project.